# ERROR running force:package:delete: entity type cannot be updated: Package

Tags: salesforcedx, delete, 2gmp

When I try to execute an sfdx command

```
sfdx force:package:delete -p 0Ho1n000000PAwZCAW
```

I see an error

```
ERROR running force:package:delete:  entity type cannot be updated: Package
```

Why do I see this error and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default devhub username wasn't set to the username of the dev hub in which the package was created.

It is possible to findout the current devhub username by executing the command

```
sfdx config:get defaultdevhubusername
```

and then you can either set the correct devhub by commands

```
sfdx config:set defaultdevhubusername=devhub
sfdx force:package:delete -p 0Ho1n000000PAwZCAW
```

or specify devhub by the -v parameter if you don't want to change the default devhub username

```
sfdx force:package:delete -p 0Ho1n000000PAwZCAW -v devhub
```